# How can we use group by keyword on PIVOT table having dynamic column joined with another table or alternative query of Pivot

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, group-by, pivot

I have 2 tables named tblDemo and tblSubDemo;
tblDemo havve 2 columns _id and _name.
tblSubDemo have 3columns, ID,Name, Demo_ID(it is the primary key of tblDemo that is foreign key).
Here is my Query:

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @PivotColumnNames AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @PivotSelectColumnNames AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column
SELECT @PivotColumnNames= ISNULL(@PivotColumnNames + ',','')
+ QUOTENAME(Name)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM tblSubDemo) AS Names

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column with isnullcase when @PivotSelectColumnNames is not Null then 1 end

SELECT @PivotSelectColumnNames 
    =  ISNULL(@PivotSelectColumnNames + ',','')
    + 'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(Name) + ', 0) AS '
    + QUOTENAME(Name)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM tblSubDemo) AS Courses
--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic
SET @DynamicPivotQuery =
'SELECT ID, _name, ' + @PivotSelectColumnNames + '
FROM tblSubDemo I
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblDemo M
ON I.Demo_Id = M._id
PIVOT(avg(Demo_ID)
FOR Name IN (' + @PivotColumnNames + ')) AS PVTTable order by _name'
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

it is giving result as
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTSjY.png)

What i want is to replace all values greater than 1 to 1 or you can say only 0s and 1s are allowed other 2 and 3 and 4 will be replaced by 1 also.another problem is that about _name column not to repeat same names row by row but group by them according to _name table.
this is the image below attached type of result i want
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaWKw.png)

this site is not allowing the image to be displayed so please just click the link and see the images

Comment: MySQL? Looks a lot like MS SQL Server.

Comment: Please also provide some example data, both the source and desired results. [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: I changed the tag from mysql to sql-server, because it's clearly not MySQL syntax.